# SanilSVN commit fails with error access forbidden

Tags: svn

i recently installed SnailSVN Lite and i am trying to commit changes to my repository. In Terminal all works well when using 'svn commit', but in SNailSVN Lite i get the following error:

```
svn: E170013: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://...'
svn: E175013: Access to '/svn/...' forbidden
```

It doesn't seem to be a credentials problem since using a different password results in a different error, but i definetely have access since comitting via terminal works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check the URL you are entering. And the server logs if you have access to them. Typically this particular error message is given when your user account doesn't have permissions to Write to that URL in your server (i.e., so far this looks like permissions-related issue).

Comment: the url is correct, after all i didn't have to enter it again, since SnailSVN read it from the already checked out directory...
And as i said, my user has the permissions, which is proven by the ability to commit via terminal

Comment: nvm, we found the problem. Appearently the authentication is not case-sensitive regarding the user, but svn is(when checking permissions)